# App crashes on start every time

Tags: crash, startup

I have an app that's already on the iOS App Store.  I recently changed just a few things which really had nothing to do with the code, tested the app and it worked fine.  I sent it away for review, but the update was denied, because it crashed on startup during the review. I've now updated Xcode from 4.1 to 4.3.3, and now my app won't start in either the simulator or on my iPhone.  Xcode says No Issues but it still won't work.

It seems to crash in dyld_start

```
0x8fe19063:  movl   %ebp, %esp     <- Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_1386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

Does anyone have any idea what this means ?

Comment: related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11043067/212858

Comment: Nothing that helped me there unfortunately, and i can't for the love of me find out whats wrong, cause it worked fine on Xcode 4.1

Comment: The instruction you've identified is a standard way to set up the stack frame at the beginning of a function.  This implies that your stack has been smashed.  Because this is happening in `dyld_start`, it's possible that you have a dynamic library  version mismatch somewhere.  Have you recompiled from scratch?  Are you sure that your app isn't linking old libraries?  Under OS X, you could check this with `otool -L <executable>`.  I'm not sure how to do this for an iPhone simulator app, but I'm sure that there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well for a OSX application - it turned out that there were a few dylibs out of place (my CMake script had shuffled them around) and the main binary couldn't get started.

Don't know if you can view console output on an iOS app, but I solved mine by starting the app from the terminal window and seeing the complaints it would spit out about missing dylibs - it appears the dylib loader will spit complaints to stdout/stderr.  I'm new to XCode, so I don't know how to get at those errors within it.